# How to use a an address formula as the limits of the COUNTIF range

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, countif

E.g.

```
=COUNTIF(M13:O24,"S3")
```

I want M13 to instead be the value $W$13 which is in a cell given by

```
=ADDRESS(1+12,11+MATCH(AG12, Plan!$L$12:$Z$12, 0),1,)
```

I want O24 to instead be the value $W$51 which is in a cell given by

```
=ADDRESS(AG18,11+MATCH(AG12, Plan!$L$12:$Z$12, 0),1,)
```

I tried substituting the two address formulas in either side of the COUNTIF range like this

```
=COUNTIF(ADDRESS(1+12,11+MATCH(AG12, Plan!$L$12:$Z$12, 0),1,):ADDRESS(AG18,11+MATCH(AG12, Plan!$L$12:$Z$12, 0),1,),"S3")
```

But it just returns an error.

FYI. The objective is for the range to expand depending on the time of the day. $W$13 and $W$51 are the top and bottom cell of a column of time values from the start of the day to the current time. The countif is used to find how many hours of a certain activity called "S3" should be completed by the current time of the day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be overthinking this. If the Date/Time value is in column X, you could use Countifs like this

=Countifs(W:W,"S3",X:X,">"&today())

This will count the S3 occurrences for the current day only.

If you want to use the Address approach, you need to wrap that into an INDIRECT, so it returns a real range, not just text.

```
=COUNTIF(Indirect(
           ADDRESS(1+12,11+MATCH(AG12, Plan!$L$12:$Z$12, 0),1,)
              &":"& 
           ADDRESS(AG18,11+MATCH(AG12, Plan!$L$12:$Z$12, 0),1,)
         )
 ,"S3")
```

I've added some indents for better readability.

Comment: Thanks for accepting. Which approach did you take?

Comment: Thanks teylyn. Indirect worked perfectly :) I probably should have taken the countif approach like you said but I couldn't really figure out how to do it (I am a bit of a novice).

It doesn't really matter anymore as Indirect worked but just FYI for a clearer image of why I was trying to do. See the highlighted cells? http://i.imgur.com/htGqfVT.png I wanted this to be my range but I wanted the bottom of that range to vary according to the time of the day given by =NOW()-TODAY() so that I could see how far or in front of schedule I was at the current moment.